# How to Setup WiFi-Tethering to Android Things for Raspberry Pi3

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3

I try this code but it is not work.
Error message is hear.

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.androidthings.myproject was not granted this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS."

```
    private void wifiTetheringOn(){
    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    try {
        Method method = wifi.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
        Log.i(TAG,method.invoke(wifi, null, true).toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: ", e);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" 
    uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
```

thanks

Comment: Your manifest file needs a permission seems like

Comment: `Your manifest file needs a permission seems like `. Very unclear remark. Which one @cricket_007?

Comment: @greenapps Well, seems I missed it in the question, but the one the error said was missing :)

Comment: Not sure about Android Things, but ... "If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, **and** it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running" -- https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Thank you cricket_007. I tryed requestPermissions() but Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS is permission denied.

Comment: In 'Android Things' 8.1  the function `setWifiApEnabled` is deprecated and removed (does nothing and returns false) .   Thus this won't work.  The Javadoc says to try `ConnectivityManager.startTethering(int, boolean, ConnectivityManager . OnStartTetheringCallback )`

Answer (score 1):

i already tried for creating Wifi tethering in raspberry PI 3 and found that currently we can not create wifi tethering for internet sharing .You can also look at my raised question at android things forum at [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63792058)

You can use `startLocalOnlyHotspot` introduce in android 7 but it will not share internet , only allow local connection .

Reference [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#startLocalOnlyHotspot(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback,%20android.os.Handler))

NOTE : For `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` if you set target below android 7 then it will not create exception but still i found that it does not allow any connection to that hotspot.